# KeyNotFoundException in Startup ConfigureServices AddMvc()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Since 30.05.2018 my ASP.NET Core code in Startup.cs

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add services to the collection.
   services.AddMvc();
}
```

throw exception as below :

An error occurred while starting the application.
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

> KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.get_Item(TKey key)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver.ComputeClassification(string
>   dependency)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider+CandidateResolver+d__4.MoveNext()
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+d__17.MoveNext()
>   System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator.MoveNext()
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection
>   services) MyWebApiProject.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) in Startup.cs
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

csproj

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.6.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" Version="0.2.0-preview2-22683" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="3.0.61" />
<PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.4.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.3" />
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was suffering the same issues. The options to remedy this are outlined here https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3132

For me I choose the option of adding the ApplicationPartManager before adding MVC, eg.

```
var manager = new ApplicationPartManager();
manager.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly));

services.AddSingleton(manager);
services.AddMvc();
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/3132#issuecomment-388082725)

Comment: Thanks, it fix my problem.

Comment: What is the Project1.Project1 Type a placeholder for? It seems to be solution specific, what should it be pointing to

Comment: This seems to have resolved it for us (with out the Project1 part) aswell. Thank you very much!

Comment: I ignore part with "Project1.Project1Type".

Comment: That did the trick for me as well.  I've really regretted using ASP.NET core at times because of quirky things like this.  I made no changes to my project other than updating Visual Studio 2017, and that cost me 45 minutes of trying to figure out what happened.  Microsoft needs to get their act together, this is inexcusable.

Answer (score 2):

We were facing the same exact issue starting a few days ago as well.

We also noticed that both we and you were using AspNetCore 1.1 (a fairly old version).

On a hunch, we updated to the latest (2.1) and that resolved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the exact same issue too. This is how far we have isolated the problem to:
1. Rebuilding an an older version of the code results in a change to XXXXX.deps.json in the build artifacts.

```
 "compilationOptions": {
"defines": [
  "TRACE",
  "DEBUG",
  "NET461"
],
```

Became

```
"compilationOptions": {
"defines": [
  "TRACE",
  "DEBUG",
  "NETFRAMEWORK",
  "NET461"
],
```

And

```
      "HealthBizModel/1.0.0": {
    "runtime": {
      "HealthBizModel.dll": {}
    }
  },
  "HealthBizService/1.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "HealthBizModel": "1.0.0"
    },
```

Became (the dependencies section is what breaks it)

```
  "HealthBizModel/1.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.Runtime.Reference1": "4.0.20.0",
      "System.Net.Primitives.Reference1": "4.0.10.0",
      "System.Net.Http.WebRequest": "4.0.0.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
      "HealthBizModel.dll": {}
    }
  },
  "HealthBizService/1.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "HealthBizModel": "1.0.0",
      "System.Text.Encoding.Reference1": "4.0.10.0"
    },
```

And interestingly, we found that if we roll back that second segment, removing the dependencies, the web app starts up and runs completely fine. So if your in an emergency this

Further resolution attempts:
 - Clean unused dependencies from effected projects (worked for 1 build but strangely started failing again
 - Added a new VS2017 build agent to the agent pool and built with that instead: also did not change.

We will also try a few more thinks like @Scott Willis 's upgrading to dotnet core 2.0

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I switched to another machine. My global.json file got corrupted and I needed to retrieve it. This is all it contained. It was pointing to a compatible version of the sdk :

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Replacing the global.json and building it gave me a missing sdk error and running the below command in the command prompt confirmed it.

```
dotnet --info
```

**I had to download and install the version of .net core SDK mentioned in that global.json**